# What view is revealed when panning UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swipe, gestures

I am panning UITableViewCell contentView as in the code below. I would like to know what is the view that exists behind the UITableViewCell contentView that is being moved?

The reason I ask is because I want to change the color of this "revealed view". I would like to customize the color underneath each tableViewCell when the cell is swiped. For example, if you left swipe the 3rd row, you see blue behind the cell. If you left swipe the 4th row, you see green behind the cell.

```
- (void)panGestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    //...

    if ((recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan
         || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
        && [recognizer numberOfTouches] > 0) {

        CGPoint location1 = [recognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location1];           
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.tableView];
        cell.contentView.frame = CGRectOffset(cell.contentView.bounds, translation.x, 0);
    }

    //...
}
```

One thing I tried was to create a UIView and add it into the cell behind the contentView. This works, but not to my satisfaction. If you put in code to animate cell deletion with UITableViewRowAnimationLeft, the color of the background will move left along with the cell. This makes sense because the background view that I created moves along with the entire cell when the animation moves the cell out to delete it. The behavior that I want is for the background color to actually be behind the cell, so it does not move when the cell is moved in the deletion animation.

The following code is how I add a background view to a cell and put it below the contentView.

```
[cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.tableView.rowHeight)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[cell addSubview:view];  
[cell bringSubviewToFront:cell.contentView];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AH HA!

I found an elegant and wonderful solution to this. I'm jittering with joy.

I added another view to the right of the cell.contentView with the background color that I want. Now when you swipe the cell, the rightSideView gets pulled along with it so it looks like it's the view that is being revealed. (Now if you wanted to put content in there, that's another complication for another person... I'm not doing that) All I wanted to do was have each cell be able to have a different reveal color. Yay! Note, you have to make the frame extra long (i.e., 500) so that the swipe to delete looks right.

Here's my code.

```
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 500, self.tableView.rowHeight)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:label];
```